# When performing Path > Trace Bitmap in Inkscape, and doing multiple passes, is there a place where I can access to the list of passes?

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg, layers, bitmap

My apologies if the terms are not the best, I just started using Inkscape yesterday.
I am using this software to transform any image into SVGs with shades of grey. On the picture down below I did 9 passes in grey level of a tree image. I then get a grey version based on the 9 passes that are combined.

I need a lot of passes to keep quite a good amount of details, however I want to combine them into 3 total layers at the end.

I can select each passes on their own and move them, however this is a bit clunky if I want to combine passes 1, 2 and 3, then passes 4, 5 and 6, then 7, 8 and 9 into 3 total layers. As, I need to move stuff around so I can see which one is which, and I don't want that because it will mess the end result.

Hence my question, is there a place where I can access the 9 passes into a list? (like the list of layers at the bottom right).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved! It's located in the top menu : Object > Objects.
The list of them appear on the right.

Comment: Hi, Riyuji, please refine your answer using a more formal language and perhaps adding a screenshot of the object navigator. Then, you can mark it as accepted.